# List of programming languages

Tags: data-request, programming

I am looking for a large list of as many programming languages possible. The largest resource I have found so far was http://java.dzone.com/articles/big-list-256-programming , but even that is missing quite a few languages.

Comment: Any problem with Wikipedia? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Lists_of_programming_languages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ohloh is the worlds largest tracker of open source projects, it compares activity level as well as programming languages by lines of code, might be useful if your interested in use stats and trends. https://www.ohloh.net/tools

Answer (score 2):

[The Language List](http://people.ku.edu/~nkinners/LangList/Extras/langlist.htm) is an effort to list programming languages.

It contains 2500 languages, and for each language at least a description, and sometimes [more data](http://people.ku.edu/~nkinners/LangList/Extras/entry.htm).

No license information.